# map_server for indigo

Tags: navigation, mapping, map-server, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

How do I get/install the map_server package for indigo?

Thank you,

Andreass

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189123/map_server-for-indigo/) by [oinkmaster2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/19948/oinkmaster2000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-map-server
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3